# Is there any way to intercept and "change" a python request response body?

Tags: python, http, request

I want to inspect all the requests (just as charles, fiddler and some other web interceptors does), and when it find the request matching, it'll fake the request response body

Example: my program logged a get session from website https://thisisnotareal.link?query=999, and the website would return `{"status":"error"}`, but before it returns the error i want to force the response body to be `{"status":"noterror"}` just as Charles Proxy does on Map Local/Rewrite function.

I've searched on stackoverflow but didnt found anything that matches what i want (at least on my search)

Idk if that's possible but i hope there is a way

Also im using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various way to achieve it by using Charles or Proxyman

**Charles**

- Map Local: Right click on the request -> Map Local -> Map to a local file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2020 01:40:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin

{
  "status": "noterror"
}
```

- Rewrite: Create a rule that matches with your request -> Change Body -> Set {"status":"noterror"}

**Proxyman**

- Map Local: Right Click on the request -> Tools -> Map Local: It will automatically create a local file for you.

[image: Map Local]

- Scripting: It likes Rewrite, but it's flexible. You can do whatever you like by using simple Javascript Code

```js
function onResponse(context, url, request, response) {

  // Update Body
  var body = response.body;
  body["status"] = "noterror";
  response.body = body;

  // Done
  return response;
}
```